# Redis HashKey erroring out

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, redis, booksleeve

**I created a HaskKey using Boolsleve c#,** i am providing a unique field each time and my item is Json string.

```
   public virtual void AddHashSetKey(string item, string hashField)
    {
        _redisClient.Hashes.Set(_database, Key, hashField, item);
    }
```

After adding about thousands fields (141988)
**i try to check the number of fields in the hash key but get error below. not sure where i can find more details or why am i getting this error?**

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[1]> Exists C:
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[1]> HLEN C:
(error) ERR Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[1]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've looked locally, and it works fine. The main thoughts I have:

- are you in the correct database? (`select` in redis terms)
- is it possible that `C:` *already had* a non-hash value, and therefore the value could not actually be set in the first place? Calling any hash command (including `hset`) will fail if the value is not a hash - so if it already exists as a string: bad things
- are you checking the correct key? (noting that keys are case-sensitive)
- in particular, I notice that you aren't checked for errors; since BookSleeve is fully asynchronous, it cannot tell you about server-side errors when you call `Set`; any error will be exposed (when it arrives) via the `Task` API, via any of `await`, `.Wait()`, `.Result` or `.ContinueWith()` (or any other `Task` API of your choice)

But locally:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[1]> exists C:
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[1]> hlen C:
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[1]> hgetall C:
1) "someField"
2) "{foo:'bar'}"
```

You might also want to try:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[1]> type C:
hash
```

which tells you what type of data is stored at `C:`

Comment: type command helped me figure out what my problem was. i had zset keys by name of C: as well as hash with same name somehow they overlapped and casued issued. i gave them diffrent names and it worked. Thanks